# Git svn - one git repo per folder (pull once)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, legacy

I have a very old svn repository in front of me and need to commit it to git.
The issue is that I'm looking for a way to create a git per remote folder.

The basic structure of svn is the following :

- https://remote-svn/svn/project
- ------Project1
- -----------------Branches
- -------------------------------Branche1
- -------------------------------Branche2
- -------------------------------Branche3
- -----------------Tags
- -------------------------------Tag1
- -------------------------------Tag2
- -------------------------------Tag3
- -----------------Trunk
- ------Project2
- ...
- ------Project3
- ...
- ------Project4
- ...
- ------Project5
- ...

Is is possible to create one git per remote folder with the underlying branches ?

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50142471/4175515. Whit svn2git you can pass where the branch and tags are with arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone projects one by one:

```
git svn clone -s https://remote-svn/svn/project/Project1
git svn clone -s https://remote-svn/svn/project/Project2
git svn clone -s https://remote-svn/svn/project/Project3
…
```

Comment: Well I guess it's time to pull all the project names and hope the content are clean.